# SSIS on Red Hat Linux - Is it supported?

Tags: sql-server, linux, ubuntu, ssis, redhat

I am currently looking into a recently announced release by Microsoft where they are allowing SQL Server and SSIS to be installed on Linux installations.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup

With the SQL Server installation it seems possible to use Red Hat, Ubuntu and SUSE, but there are only installation instructions for SSIS in Ubuntu.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-ssis

I am interested in any information pertaining to installing SSIS for Linux on Red Hat, whether or not it is undocumented by Microsoft or if you know that it is currently only implemented in Ubuntu at the current time.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not convinced that this question would be a good fit for [DBA.SE]. You need to check their guidelines for what types of questions are on-topic there, and possibly ask for guidance on [Meta.DBA.SE]. So I'm not migrating at this time. Feel free to re-post on a different site if you determine it would be appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSIS on Linux supports RedHat in SQL Server 2017 RC1.

Try it in https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ssis/2017/07/19/ssis-on-linux-supports-redhat-in-sql-server-2017-rc1/

Comment: Thank you for this, I have reached out and once I get a response I will mark this as the answer